# connect Epson Printer TM-U220 with ePOS-Device SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing, epson

Printer TM-U220 is connected to router and able to print something like

> GET /HTTP/1.1
>
> Host : 192.168.1.100:9100
>
> Accept : text/html,application/xhtml + xml,

With that, im sure that my printer is connected to the network with IP 192.168.1.100

Now, id like to connect my TM-U220 to my web application using
[ePos SDK Javascript](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_device_js_en/index.php?content_id=139)
but after trying to connect the device from my web app, im getting this

> Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.
>      http://192.168.1.100:8008/socket.io/1/?t=1473523306578

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you find a solution ? Thank